# Stuck on dates using interval

Tags: mysql

A little stuck, the end user is allowed to pick a year/month and then collect the data going back 5 months. I'm good with setting the initial date off a timestamp (yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss) column but can I use last_day in conjunction with interval. So if the end user picks May 2013 they can collect all the data from May 31, 2013 through January 1, 2013.

```
 Ex. set @d2:=concat('2013-05','-01');
     set @d1:=@d2 - last_day(interval 5 month);
     select @d1,@d2;
```

Any help/guidance is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function `LAST_DAY` [takes a date as an argument](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_last-day), not an interval.

It would appear that the code you want is:

```
set @d1 := LAST_DAY(@d2 - INTERVAL 5 MONTH)
```

Comment: Thanks for this code but no good deed goes unpunished. I ran the code but I wind up with "2012-12-31"=@d1 rather than "2013-01-01"=@d1. Is it possible to add a day at @d1?

Comment: If you really want to add a day you can do `LAST_DAY(@d2 - INTERVAL 5 MONTH) + INTERVAL 1 DAY`

Comment: You rock! Spot on to what I needed. Thanks for you help.

Comment: Then again, if you have `>= 2013-01-01` it would be the same as `> 2012-12-31` and you don't have to add the addition

Comment: Hmmm, that would definitely be more straight-forward. Typically don't work with dates except for this new client and its crash-course time.